# find the area of the equilateral triangle inscribed in a circle $x^2+y^2+2gx+2fy+c=0$ ?

Tags: geometry, circles

I am stuck on the following problem:

> How can I find the area of the equilateral triangle inscribed in a circle $x^2+y^2+2gx+2fy+c=0$ ?

Answer is given to be : $\frac{3\sqrt 3}{4}(g^2+f^2-c)$ sq. unit.

Can someone please explain?

Comment: Сигурно е толкова.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: First complete the square, giving an equation like $(x-h)^2+(y-k)^2 = r^2$. From this you can deduce the radius of the circle; then apply known formulas to figure out the area of the inscribed equilateral triangle (if you don't know these, look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equilateral_triangle) for example).

Answer (score 1):

In brief: Complete the square in your equation.

$$x^2+y^2+2gx+2fy+c=0$$
$$x^2+2gx+y^2+2fy=-c$$
$$x^2+2gx+g^2+y^2+2fy+f^2=g^2+f^2-c$$
$$(x+g)^2+(y+f)^2=\left(\sqrt{g^2+f^2-c}\right)^2$$

This is the standard form of an equation of a circle. We see that the radius of the circle is $\sqrt{g^2+f^2-c}$.

Now use that to find the area of the inscribed circle. That is straightforward geometry: let us know if you have difficulty with that.